# Is it compulsory to use Apache Kafka while using Apache storm?

Tags: hbase, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I want to implement Storm for real time message processing in my project. I have observed that many people use 'Apache Kafka' along with 'Storm'.

In my project client applications will send messages to server side and server side is supposed to authenticate messages, process them and store into HBase. Only constraint is that message should not get dropped, each and every message must be persisted into HBase, it is fine if it takes few minutes to process that message.

I would like to know

1. Is it mandatory to use Kafka with Storm?
2. What are the advantages of using Kafka with Storm?
3. What will happen if I don't use Kafka with storm?

Request you to please enlighten me on usage of Kafka.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. There is no need to use Kafka together with Storm. Both systems are independent from each other
2. Kafka is a reliable message queue, thus, is helps Storm topologies to provide fault-tolerance (ie, it simplifies the implementation of so-called reliable Spouts)
3. See (2) -> ie, if you want to have fault-tolerance guarantees, you need to take care about reliability in your Spouts by yourself

If you want to process and authenticate your incoming messages in Storm before persisting them to HBase, I would recommend that you use Kafka. Kafka would act as a buffer in which each incoming message is reliably stored. Storm can consume the message from Kafka. If a message is lost within Storm, the message can be re-read from Kafka. After persisting the message to HBase, Kafka can drop the message.

Comment: awesome...thanks a lot for clear and detailed answer.